# SQL table array

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

Can I have an array of tables or a way to add tables or columns dynamically through the code?
What I am trying is this:

```
private static final String [] TABLE_NAME = new String ['value to be set in code'];
```

Comment: Don't declare it `static final` and you can compute it at runtime. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Remember that all Java code must be inside a class. You should edit your question to include the class declaration as part of your code snippet.

Comment: `Can I have an array of tables or a way to add tables or columns dynamically through the code?` **NO**. Because each time you *alter the database structure* (i.e.: by adding or removing a table or a column), you must then increase the value of the DATABASE_VERSION constant. Or delete the database and re-create it.

Comment: I just want to set the number at runtime, so no recreating of the data bass

Comment: But you asked for `a way to add tables or columns dynamically`

Comment: @Rotwang it appears that you are correct and I owe you an apology, but thanks for the recreating the database advice

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, you don't owe anything. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The value inside the `[]` is the array size. You can certainly allocate this dynamically with something like

```
public class MyTables {
    private static final int TABLE_COUNT = 2;
    private static final String [] TABLE_NAME = new String [TABLE_COUNT];
}
```

However, you still need to populate the array with `String` objects for the names. The most obvious way is to do this in a method which must be called explicitly:

```
public class MyTables {
    private static final int TABLE_COUNT = 2;
    private static final String [] TABLE_NAME = new String [TABLE_COUNT];

    public static void initTableNames() {
        TABLE_NAME[0] = "TABLE1";
        TABLE_NAME[1] = "TABLE2";
    }
}
```

The disadvantage is that you have to call this explicitly with `MyTables.initTableNames()` somewhere in your code. Java provides `static` initializers to avoid this problem:

```
public class MyTables {
    private static final int TABLE_COUNT = 2;
    private static final String [] TABLE_NAME = new String [TABLE_COUNT];

    static {
        TABLE_NAME[0] = "TABLE1";
        TABLE_NAME[1] = "TABLE2";
    }
}
```

Now, `TABLE_NAME` will be populated as soon as you use the `MyTable` class.

But all of this is much more complicated than necessary because you can combine this all into a single line in the declaration:

```
public class MyTables {
    private static final String [] TABLE_NAME = {"TABLE1", "TABLE2"};
}
```

Comment: Can't I use for loops to set the String values and what how can I use the `MyTables.initTableNames() ` method?

Comment: @Omar Yes, in my examples you can use a for loop since the table names follow a pattern.

Comment: @Omar You use `MyTables.initTableNames()` by typing `MyTables.initTableNames()`. However, I suggest that you use a static initialize rather than a static method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying ? you want to know what are the tables in your sqlite database, and how these table name can be stored in TABLE_NAME array you mentioned in the question ?

If it is, you can use Cursor  with query `select tbl_name  from sqlite_master  where type ="table"` , and fetch the data in the array.  In sqlite_master table you will find the information of all table, views and corresponding sqls.